# Jekyll build failing on GH-pages

Tags: ruby, git, jekyll, github-pages

I'm having an intermittent issue where my Jekyll site fails to build due to a gem installer error:

`Gem::InstallError: public_suffix requires Ruby version >= 2.0.`

My understanding is that Pages runs Ruby 2.x, but Travis shows v1.9.3 during the failed build.

I haven't built the site locally - just forked a repo, bumped a few files via prose.io, and the build fails. I had the same issue a couple of days ago on committing a new post, but it seemed to resolve itself.

Any suggestions as to how to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

Per [this issue](https://github.com/github/pages-gem/issues/122#issuecomment-158942037) (the very first result when I googled your error message), you need to explicitly specify your Ruby version in `.travis.yml`:

> The current TravisCI default Ruby 1.9.3 is now too old for the pages gem (see http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/ruby/#Supported-Ruby-Versions), so we should ask TravisCI to use Ruby 2.1.1 to match what is currently used on GitHub pages (https://pages.github.com/versions/).
>
> i.e. your `.travis.yml` should include:
>
> ```yaml
> language: ruby
> rvm: 2.1.1
> script: "bundle exec jekyll build"
> ```

Comment: Updating .travis.yml and adding a reference to pygments.rb in my Gemfile passes the Travis build but still fails at GH pages end. Must be something else - GH error message is useless.

Comment: You should change your highlighter from pygments to `rouge`, as from May 1st on, GH Pages will no longer support pygments. Ruby version used by GH Pages is currently 2.1.7.